# Download images from media library to computer in BULK?

Tags: php, images, ftp

All I want is to download all images from the media library to my computer. I don't want to then use them in another site. I uploaded them from a camera card while traveling, and then it was stolen. These are now the only copies, and I would like them on my computer now that I'm home. I don't know how to use PHP very well.

What seems like the most logical solution is for there to be an option under BULK ACTIONS to "Download." The only option currently listed is to "Delete Permanently." I feel like downloading a site's media content is an option that should have been made available from the start of WP.

Can I get it with FTP? From what I read WP doesn't allow FTP. Can someone give me a simple guide to utilizing a PHP script to collect the files?

Comment: What do you mean WP doesn't allow FTP? Are you on WordPress.com or your own hosting setup?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, download them via FTP.

Just connect to your server, then navigate to `/wp-content/uploads` to see all of your uploads.  By default, they're organized into directories: `/{year}/{month}/{file}` ... so `/2012/05/my-image.jpg` for example.

Answer (score 1):

If the WordPress blog in question is on wordpress.com, tough luck - you can't access the files via FTP, and the official support is only open to paying customers.

Rather than writing a custom script for this, I suggest you use something like [wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) or [DownThemAll!](http://www.downthemall.net/).